# Computational modeling of steric repulsion between two polymer mediated magnetic Nanoparticle?

Tags: physical-chemistry, computational-chemistry, surface-chemistry, nanotechnology

Can you recommend any modern article or research papers on steric interactions and forces between two or multiple magnetic nanoparticles with polymer brushes in a nonpolar solvents? something with more physics and mathematical formulas not just text and graphs. My goal is to learn how brushes create osmotic pressure, what are the forces, and then create a simulation of two particles interacting together.

I am new to this field and currently reading ***Israelachvili's Inter-molecular Forces*** and ***Flory's Polymers*** books they are very general and don't have detailed Physics in case of steric repulsion.